# Remove the odd element from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list, which contains more lists with elements, see example
`{{1, 1, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 3, 4, 3}}`

I want to remove num 2 from the first list and num 3 from the second list and num 4 from the third list. Suppose i don't know the value of the element and don't know the position of the element i want to remove. I want the function or whatever to return `{{x,x,x,x},{y,y,y,y},{z,z,z,z}}`

Is it possible to do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: So what is really the case? Is there always only one element which is different?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 13):

```
Most @ CommonestFilter[#, 2] & /@ data
```

when all initial sublists have the same length you could skip `Map`:

```
CommonestFilter[
  data,
  {0, 2}
  ][[;; , 2 ;;]]
```

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of either of those functions

Comment: @JasonB You are welcome. :) Well it's the first time I'm using this filter too :)

Answer (score 3):

```
(Gather /@ {{1, 1, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 3, 4, 
     3}, {8, 8, 7, 8, 8}})[[All, 1]]
(* {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {8, 8, 8, 8}} *)
```

Will work so long as the element you want to keep is first in the list, but it fails here

```
(Gather /@ {{1, 1, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 3, 4, 
     3}, {8, 8, 7, 8, 8}, {4, 9, 9, 9, 9}})[[All, 1]]
(* {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {8, 8, 8, 8}, {4}} *)
```

So first use `Gather`, then sort by `Length`, so that you are choosing the list with the most number of elements.

This function does the trick

```
removeoddelement[list_] := Last@SortBy[Gather[list], Length]

removeoddelement@{11, 11, 90, 11, 11}
(* {11, 11, 11, 11} *)

removeoddelement /@ {{192, 12, 12, 12, 12}, {118, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {2, 2, 2, 165, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 112}, {113, 14, 14, 14, 
   14}, {14, 91, 14, 14, 14}, {5, 5, 5, 5, 150}, {6, 6, 6, 186, 
   6}, {5, 5, 5, 108, 5}, {15, 15, 15, 151, 15}, {10, 10, 10, 76, 
   10}, {3, 3, 3, 174, 3}, {14, 162, 14, 14, 14}, {7, 139, 7, 7, 
   7}, {4, 4, 73, 4, 4}, {115, 14, 14, 14, 14}, {135, 10, 10, 10, 
   10}, {1, 1, 1, 119, 1}, {7, 165, 7, 7, 7}, {5, 5, 149, 5, 5}}
(* {{12, 12, 12, 12}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 
  3}, {14, 14, 14, 14}, {14, 14, 14, 14}, {5, 5, 5, 5}, {6, 6, 6, 
  6}, {5, 5, 5, 5}, {15, 15, 15, 15}, {10, 10, 10, 10}, {3, 3, 3, 
  3}, {14, 14, 14, 14}, {7, 7, 7, 7}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {14, 14, 14, 
  14}, {10, 10, 10, 10}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {7, 7, 7, 7}, {5, 5, 5, 5}} *)
```

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2};

ConstantArray[#, Count[list, #]] &[First @ Commonest[list, 1]]
```

> {2, 2, 2, 2}

Comment: or `Cases[list,First@Commonest@list]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a pipeline of curried functions, like so:

```
In[1]:= Map[
         Counts /* TakeLargest[1] /* KeyValueMap[ConstantArray] /* Flatten, 
         rows]
Out[1]= {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3}}
```

That keeps the most common element. This will delete any singleton elements:

```
In[2]:= Map[
         Counts /* DeleteCases[1] /* KeyValueMap[ConstantArray] /* Flatten, 
         rows]
Out[2]= {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The odd element is necessarily the first or the last if the list were sorted, so either taking the second-smallest or second-largest element should work:

```
RankedMin[#, 2] & /@ data
RankedMax[#, 2] & /@ data
```

You could also take the median, though it would probably be slower.

This avoids the overhead of sorting each entire list or storing frequencies in a map (though I suppose it could be slow if your numbers are complex expressions that are hard to compare).

Comment: In each sublist, the second smallest (or second largest) is guaranteed not to be the odd one out. It shouldn't matter if the outlier is smaller in some lists and larger in others.

Comment: Ah, ok, that's smart. :) But your approach is only returning one value for each sublist which is not exactly what OP wants. Maybe you can add a ConstantArray or something

Comment: My mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your statement was precisely what you need (remove `n + 1` from the `n`th list), then this will work:

```
list = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 3, 4, 3};
MapIndexed[DeleteCases[#1, 1 + First@#2] &, list]
(* {{1, 1, 1, 1,}, {2, 2, 2, 2,}, {3, 3, 3, 3} *)
```

I suspect somehow that this isn't the general use case, however.